# Elementary equivalence between a well-ordering and linear ordering

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Consider a language $L$ consisting of a binary predicate $R$ and some additional predicates (e.g. $=$) so that the $L$-structure $M=(U_{M},R_{M})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},<_{\mathbb{N}})$.

I am trying to construct an $L$-structure $M'=(U_{M'},R_{M'})$ such that

1. $M\equiv M'$ (that is, $M$ and $M'$ satisfy the same $L$-sentences)
2. $M'$ contains an infinite descending sequence, i.e. there exist elements $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n},\ldots\in U_{M'}$ such that $\langle a_{n+1},a_{n}\rangle\in R_{M'}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My first thought was to try with $M'=(\mathbb{Z},<_{\mathbb{Z}})$, but this fails since $M$ does not satisfy the $L$-sentence $\forall x \exists y Ryx$.

Then I considered $R_{M'} = R_{M}\cup\{\langle a_{k+1},a_{k}\rangle : k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where these $a_{k}$ are new constants. If we consider any finite subset of $R_{M'}$, by an appropriate map we can show that it is satisfiable in the structure $M$ (as $M$ as descending sequences of arbitrary finite length). Then by the compactness theorem $R_{M'}$ is satisfiable is some $L$-structure $M'=(U_{M'},R_{M'})$. Here is where I begin to have troubles:

1. Is $U_{M'}$ simply the union of $U_{M}$ (i.e. $\mathbb{N}$) and the set of new constants $\{a_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$?
2. Is this $M'$ just obtained by the Compactness theorem and $L$-structure? Since I have introduced constants this is not altogether clear to me because of the following question.
3. In trying to show that $M\equiv M$ I run into sentences with the new constants. But these are not $L$-sentences. Or do I have to consider a language $L'=L\cup\{a_{k}: k\in\mathbb{N}\}$? That is, how do I prove that $M$ and $M'$ satisfy the same $L$-sentences?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a big problem with your attempt: $R_{M'}$ is a binary relation, not a theory. So when you write "by the compactness theorem $R_{M'}$ is satisfiable...", this makes no sense. I think clarifying this for yourself will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you. The statement of the Compactness Theorem in the notes I am reading (Mathematical Logic by Stephen G. Simpson): "Let $S$ be set of sentences of the predicate calculus. $S$ is satisfiable if an only if each finite subset of $S$ is satisfiable". Perhaps I should consider (in place of $R_{M'}$) a set who is the union of two sets: The first is the set of all $L$-sentences satisfied by $M$, and the other the set $\{\langle a_{k+1},a_{k}\rangle:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ as I state above.

Comment: What about $M'=\Bbb N\cup^*\Bbb Z$ with  $n<z$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z,\ z\in\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Berci Is this an $L$- structure? Why are $M$ and $M'$ elementary equivalent? Would you care to write and answer?

Comment: @John You're getting closer, but you're still mixing together sets of sentences and relations. What you want is the union of (1) the set of all $L$-sentences satisfied by $M$, and (2) the set $\{R(a_{k+1},a_k)\mid k\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Note that (2) is a set of sentences, while the set you wrote down $\{\langle a_{k+1},a_k\rangle \mid k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a set of ordered pairs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following MSE related questions: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134854/proving-that-two-structures-are-elementarily-equivalent-using-the-tarski-vaught) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134721/understanding-the-meaning-of-and-difference-between-elementary-equivalence-eq) appear directly related to Berci's comment to my question. Then there is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373646/a-structure-elementarily-equivalent-to-mathbbn-0-operatornames-cdot?rq=1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673512/question-on-a-proof-of-elementarily-equivalent-but-not-isomorphic), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/example-of-non-isomorphic-structures-which-are-elementarily-equivalent).
In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329892/non-isomorphic-structures-of-the-same-cardinality-which-are-elementary-equivalen?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329960/simple-examples-of-non-isomorphic-but-elementarily-equivalent-structures) Alex Kruckman, whose comments I find quite helpful, provides good answers.

The gist of the argument is to find a set $S$ of sentences (in the language $L$ with parameters $V$) which contain the set of all valid $L$-sentences in $M$ (so that any $L$-$V$-structure's reduct to $L$ without the parameters will be elementary equivalent to $M$), but which also includes sentences describing a phenomenon which does not happen in $M$. We then show that any finite subset of $S$ is satisfiable and the Compactness Theorem takes care of the rest.

Consider the set $T$ of all $L$-sentences $A$ such that $M\vDash A$. Also, consider a set of new parameters $V=\{a_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, i.e. not occurring in $M$. Then define the set

$$S=T\cup\{Ra_{k+1}a_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$

We will show that $S$ is finitely satisfiable. Indeed, consider a finite subset $S_{0}\subset S$. Then, the set $C$ of parameters mentioned in the expressions contained in $S_{0}$ is finite. let $\varphi:V\rightarrow U_{M}$ be a map sending $C$ to an appropriate finite descending sequence of elements of $U_{M}$ in the sense that $\langle\varphi(a_{k+1}),\varphi(a_{k})\rangle\in R_{M}$ whenever $Ra_{k+1}a_{k}\in S_{0}$ (such a $\varphi$ can always be found since $U_{M}$ has descending sequences of arbitrary finite length). Clearly the $L$-$V$-structure $(M,\varphi)$ satisfies $S_{0}$.

By the Compactness Theorem there is an $L$-$V$-structure $(M',\phi)$ satisfying $S$. Note that $M'=(U_{M'},R_{M'})$ is an $L$-structure. Moreover, for any $L$-sentence $A$,
$$M\vDash A\Rightarrow A\in T\Rightarrow M'\vDash A.$$

On the other hand,

$$M\nvDash A\Rightarrow M\vDash(\neg A)\Rightarrow (\neg A)\in T\Rightarrow M'\vDash(\neg A)\Rightarrow M'\nvDash\neg A.$$

Therefore $M\equiv M'$. In particular, $M'$ is a linear ordering because the $L$-sentences 1-5 below are satisfied by $M'$.

1. $\forall x\;\neg Rxx$.
2. $\forall x\forall y\;Rxy\Rightarrow\neg Ryx$.
3. $\forall x\forall y\forall z\;Rxz\wedge Ryz\Rightarrow Rxz$.
4. $\forall x\forall y\forall z\;Rxz\Rightarrow Rxy\vee Ryz$.
5. $\forall x\forall y\;(\neg Rxy) \wedge (\neg Ryx) \Rightarrow x=y$.

Finally, note that $M'$ contains an infinite descending sequence since $(M',\phi)\vDash S$ means that $M'\vDash R\phi(a_{k+1})\phi(a_{k})$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and this means that for the elements $\phi(a_{1}),\phi(a_{2}),\ldots,\phi(a_{n}),\ldots\in U_{M'}$ we have that $\langle\phi(a_{k+1})\phi(a_{k})\rangle\in R_{M'}$, as desired.

Note that $M$ is a strict well-ordering while $M'$ is not. Therefore, $M$ and $M'$ are not isomorphic $L$-structures.